# How to parse on/off (debug) flag using argparse?

Tags: python, argparse

My CLI program uses a `--debug` flag to decide whether or not to print debug messages. When `--debug` is specified, it should print debug messages; otherwise, it should not print debug messages.

My current approach is:

`parser.add_argument('--debug', help='print debug messages to stderr', nargs='?')`

However, the `--help` message suggests that this approach does not achieve my goal:

```
optional arguments:
  -h, --help       show this help message and exit
  --debug [DEBUG]  print debug messages to stderr
```

As you can see, it wants a value after the flag; however, `--debug` is an on/off argument.

What should I do instead?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use the `store_true` action instead:

```
parser.add_argument(
    '--debug',
    action='store_true', 
    help='print debug messages to stderr'
)
```

`nargs='?'` should only be used for options that take one or more arguments (with a fallback to a default value).